# Xamarin.ios .Net Embedding error: "Please use the objcgen tool for Objective-C generation"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, embeddinator

I can't get .Net embedding to convert a Xamarin.IOS class lib project so that it can be called from a Xcode Objective-C project....

I created Xamarin ios class lib project “embedinnator2 class lib “ on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 latest.
I installed Embeddinator-4000 NuGet.
I built project. 
Used PowerShell run as admin to enter project’s bin\debug\ and then executed...
C:\Users\Doug.nuget\packages\embeddinator-4000\0.4.0\tools\Embeddinator-4000.exe --gen=Obj-C --platform=ios --compile --debug --target=static  --static --verbose+ embedinnator2 class lib.dll

But then got this:

> “Please use the objcgen tool for Objective-C generation.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the readme:

> Don't use Embeddinator-4000.exe.
>
> Use mono ./bin/Debug/objcgen.exe --gen=Obj-C -o ./Output ManagedAssembly1.dll.

re: https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000/tree/master/objcgen

Comment: Everyone online says that doing .Net Embedding doesn't work on Windows platform, and to do it on MacOS.

Comment: The problem I'm now having is building objcgen from  repo clone from Github Emb-4000.  There are many .csproj Visual Studio projects.  The lone .sln gets build errors.  Which .csproj should I use?  Or can I just do "make" at the Mac terminal prompt within local repo?